# What is the correct way to retrieve variables from the URL with an IF Statement?

Tags: php, variables, url

My old website just got moved to a new server (new PHP platform).

When the URL says: `http://url.com/page.php?num=9`

This used to work:

```
if($num == "9")
echo "hello";
?>
```

What changed in the intervening thousand years since this site was built?

Comment: Query string values are in the `$_GET` array. `$_GET['num']` for example.

Answer (score 3):

in this case, you need to GET the variable use this way

```
$number = $_GET["num"];
```

Then you can continue with

```
if($number=="9") {
     echo "hello";
}
```

Comment: Also it's a good idea to filter or sanitize any information you retrieve from GET

Comment: Yes you are right. It's quite risky to use GET ... maybe using some php framework can be the solution, like Code Igniter, Laravel, and others

Answer (score 1):

What changed was:

1. PHP 4.1 - [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) ([`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), etc.) were introduced
2. PHP 4.2 - [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) default setting changed from `ON` to `OFF`
3. PHP 5.3 - Register globals was deprecated
4. PHP 5.4 - Register globals was removed

Register globals was what allowed you to automatically have `$num` available if it was in the URL. There is some discussion in the PHP documentation I linked about the various (good) reasons that feature was removed. Probably a good TL/DR (from that documentation) would be:

> When on, register_globals will inject your scripts with all sorts of variables, like request variables from HTML forms. This coupled with the fact that PHP doesn't require variable initialization means writing insecure code is that much easier.

As other answers have shown, the way to get it now is using `$_GET['num']`, but if your code was relying on register globals, there will probably be other things that need to be updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET['your_url_parameter_name_here']
```

in your instance use the below code

```
if($_GET['num'] == "9")
    echo "hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `values` from a `url` like this:

*url*: `http://example.com/page.php?num=9`

```
$_GET['num'];
```

To check if it's set, you can simply do this:

```
if(isset($_GET['num'])){
   //return true
}
```

Or for you instance, if it's 9

```
if($_GET['num'] == "9"){
   echo "It's 9";
}
```

Read about `$_GET` in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)